# Trying to compute eigenvalues using traces.

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Let $A$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$. There are $n$ eigenvalues of $A$: $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$. How can we guess $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$ using traces? We have
\begin{align}
& tr(A) = \lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n.
\end{align}
Let $D = diag(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$. Then there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $D = PAP^{-1}$. Therefore $A^2 = P^{-1}D^2P$. We have 
\begin{align}
& tr(A^2) = tr(P^{-1}D^2P) = tr(D^2)= \lambda_1^2 + \cdots + \lambda_n^2.
\end{align}
Using these results, can we find $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: Yes using [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities).

Answer (score 3):

In your argument, you have assumed that $A$ is diagonalizable and there's no need to do that. Anyway, if you know $c_1 := \operatorname{tr}(A), \dots, c_n := \operatorname{tr}(A^n)$, you can can use them together with Newton's identities to reconstruct the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and then by solving it (explicitly, if you can, or numerically), you can find the eigenvalues. Note that you don't get an explicit expression for the **eigenvalues** themselves, only for the **characteristic polynomial** of $A$ so if $n \geq 5$, you generically won't have an algebraic formula for the eigenvalues in terms of $c_n$ (which shouldn't be surprising).

For example, if $n = 2$ and you know $c_1 := \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$ and $c_2 := \lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2$ then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is given by

$$ x^2 - (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)x + (\lambda_1 \lambda_2) = x^2 - c_1 x + \frac{c_1^2 - c_2}{2}.$$

To solve for the eigenvalues, we need the roots of

$$ 2x^2 - 2c_1x + (c_1^2 - c_2) = 0 $$

which are given by

$$ \lambda_{1,2} = \frac{2c_1 \pm \sqrt{4c_1^2 - 8(c_1^2 - c_2)}}{4} = \frac{c_1 \pm \sqrt{2c_2 - c_1^2}}{2}. $$